# ggplot geom_histogram color by factor not working properly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

In trying to color my stacked histogram according to a factor column; all the bars have a "green" roof? I want the bar-top to be the same color as the bar itself. The figure below shows clearly what is wrong. All the bars have a "green" horizontal line at the top?

[image]

Here is a dummy data set :

```
BodyLength <- rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 3)

vector <- c("80","10","5","5")

colors <- c("black","blue","red","green")

color <- rep(colors,vector)

data <- data.frame(BodyLength,color)
```

And the program I used to generate the plot below :

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=data$BodyLength, color = factor(data$color), fill=I("transparent")))

plot <- plot + geom_histogram()

plot <- plot + scale_colour_manual(values = c("Black","blue","red","green"))
```

Also, since the data column itself contains color names, any way I don't have to specify them again in scale_color_manual? Can ggplot identify them from the data itself? But I would really like help with the first problem right now...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick way to get your colors to `scale_colour_manual` without writing out a vector:

```
data <- data.frame(BodyLength,color)
data$color<- factor(data$color)
```

and then later,

```
scale_colour_manual(values = levels(data$color))
```

Now, with respect to your first problem, I don't know exactly why your bars have green roofs.  However, you may want to look at some different options for the position argument in geom_histogram, such as

```
plot + geom_histogram(position="identity")
```

..or `position="dodge"`.  The `identity` option is closer to what you want but since green is the last line drawn, it overwrites previous the colors.

I like density plots better for these problems myself.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=BodyLength, color=color)) + geom_density()
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=BodyLength, fill=color)) + geom_density(alpha=.3)
```

Comment: plot+ geom_histogram(position ="identity") seems to work; except that now all the colored stacks are at the base of their respective bins i.e below the black bars. I want them on top. Thanks for trying David...I will update if I figure the problem out.

Comment: For any histogram that you draw where you have overlayed bins with differently-colored outlines and transparent bins, the graphics procedure has to make a decision on how to do the overlay.  When you have a "0" in a bin for the blue group, for example, R draws a horizontal line for the blue at Y = 0. If there is "1" in the blue bin, it will draw a rectangle with height Y = 1, and this will remain unless it is overwritten by the next group.

Comment: In my version of this, there are many black bars, since black is the most numerous.  However black is the bottom histogram layer in the overlay and green is the topmost layer; this is because of the `factor()` function.  That is why the Y = 0 line in my version is green.  The colored stacks are at the base of their respective bins because if for an arbitrary bin, if black = 5 and red = 2, then there will be two horizontal lines.  I'm having trouble visualizing how your optimal transparent histogram would appear.

Comment: If you were to do `plot <- plot + geom_histogram(position="dodge")`, you will probably see the problem with your transparent histogram approach, especially for bins near the middle. It illustrates how you have 4 colors per bin and they are competing.  How should R display a single bin with different colors overlayed?  The "roof" is the last color in the `factor()` order.  This is why you don't often see histograms constructed in the way that you're proposing.

Comment: I see. Thanks David. That addresses at least the issue properly for me to now hunt for a solution. When I make the bars filled with data$color as opposed to fill = "transparent", the issue no longer persists. The figure is for a journal and I am trying to be conservative in terms of printer ink -: